# SQL group by - can it be this simple?

Tags: sql, sql-server

can someone please check if this is correct?

[image]

Not sure if my answer to Q6 is correct, I am not sure if the group_by I am using is right or not, the rest I think is ok
Thanks

Comment: It would be very nice if you [edit]ed in a transcription of the problem and your solution to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are close. You need to:

- Use `COUNT()` instead of `SUM()`.
- There's no need to use the `HAVING` clause.
- Optionally, you can add aliases to the columns, so they become easier to read.

Your query should look like:

```
select a.author_id, count(*) as titles, sum(b.quantity_ordered) as units
from a join b on a.book_id = b.book_id
group by a.author_id
```

Comment: Oh yes thanks, a silly mistake!

Comment: Apart from that, is the group by correct?

Comment: Yes, the `GROUP BY` is correct.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply!